# Setting up Python and QGIS for standalone applications

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am learning QGIS for an upcoming internship. I have been trying to configure Python 3.7.5 with QGIS 3.8 (a Coruna) for two weeks now. I have overcome quite some issues by reading a lot of posts, but now I seem to be stuck.

I am trying to run a simple testScript.py from a windows 10 terminal and got many many errors about modules not being found etc. Solved those issues by reading a lot of posts here and elsewhere, but now I finally get access to my script's imports and also managed to get a Python GUI to open up, the cmd complains about "ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv"

Allthough,  as you can see, I did follow the hint and I do point to the folder where this file can be found:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1069]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET QGIS_PREFIX=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET PATH=%PATH%,%QGIS_PREFIX%\bin

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS_PREFIX%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\plugins

C:\Users\Kunga Led>SET GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W64\share\epsg_csv

C:\Users\Kunga Led>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Kunga Led\Desktop>python testScript.py
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

How do I solve this issue?

I have read that the OSGEO4W64 installer actually takes care of these issues by itself, but since I installed it, I haven't had anything but trouble getting stuff to run. (Of course I am totally new to this so there will be a lot I need to learn about, I just don't know exactly where to look) I would like to add that running scripts from the built-in QGIS console or editor is never a problem. The problems occur when I try to run a .py file from the commandline.

Comment: Under Windows, qgis comes with its own python, version in 3.7.0. Standalone applications should use calls to batchfiles py3_env.bat and qt5_env.bat. Trying to leave this path leads to errors and i can't recommend that for beginners. There is an exaemple to write a standalone applications in the qgis python [developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#id10)

Comment: @AndreasMüller That sounds like a plausible answer to my problem. I was not intentionally trying to leave a path. I was merely looking for "a" path. I guess I am indeed unwillingly trying to use my own version of Python to work with QGIS instead of using the version that is embedded in QGIS. Thanks for pointing that out.